# Translation into Canadian French of Customer Information

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques, québec

I've generated a French translation for these two sentences, but they don't quite sound right to me. I'd like some feedback!

Have a question or concern about your device? We’re here to help! = **Question ou préoccupation concernant votre appareil? Nous pouvons aider!**

Before returning your device, visit [URL] or call Technical Support. = **Avant de retourner votre appareil, visitez le [URL] ou appelez le support technique.**

Please advise! I don't want the text to sound too robotic or formal. How would this sound in conversational Canadian French?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would wrote it in French from France, likely suitable in Canadian French :

> Une question ou un souci avec votre appareil? Nous pouvons vous aider!
>
> Avant de nous retourner votre appareil, veuillez préalablement consulter la page [URL] ou appeler le support technique!

The only difference I'm aware of is the question and exclamation marks that sticks to the last word while a space would be required in France French typography.

Comment: Au lexique, assistance ou soutien plutôt que _support_ ? La question n'est pas claire à mon avis. Merci.

Comment: French Canadian here. This sounds fine.